# jquery find value of selected item in drop down with a twist

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors, coldfusion-8

I have a drop down list displaying values in a select tag that I would normally just use $('#ID').val() to obtain the value but the ID is either unknown or a dynamically added row.

Following the closing select tag, I have an jquery ui icon I'm using that when clicked will capture the value of drop down option currently selected (this value will be replicated to the other select lists).  This bit of code loops so I know I'll need to use some sort of .find() or .parent() or something along those lines which is still not sunk in with me yet.

Here is the source code:

```
<tr>
<th class="form"><label>SI Contact</label></th>
<td id="name_29805"><div style="float: left;">
        <select name="contactsbcuid" id="contactsbcuid_29805" sid="29805" ordr="1">
            <option value="userID1234">Doe, John</option>
            <option value="userID1235">Doe, Jane</option>
            ...
            <option value="userID1236">Smith, David</option>
        </select>
        <input name="orig_contactsbcuid" id="orig_contactsbcuid_29805" value="userID1235" sid="29805" ordr="1" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-copy vtip" onClick="CopyDown('contactsbcuid',1)" id="select_contactsbcuid_29805" title="Copy the selected value down the list." style="float: right;"></span></div></td>
```

Comment: your source code is missing please try again

Comment: I'm having a bit of difficulty formatting my source code with the coldfusion custom tag.  If this is confusing, I can rewrite this to make it easier for the broader stackoverflow community.  Despite the CF code, this is more of a jquery question than anything.

Comment: can you get show uus the code after it has been generated rthant than the coldfusion

Comment: could you show the client side code which is output?

Comment: NOTE:  ..Code in post is the generated code now, not CF..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is only a single select in the tablecell.
So it should be sufficient to find the 'td' and when you've found it search for the select.

```
var value = $(this).parents('td').find('select').val();
```

Comment: This is what I was attempting but I see you are using `parents` whereas I was using `parent`

`var vl=$(this).parent().next().find("select option:selected").val();`

... and a few other selectors  :)

Comment: I usually find .parents more easy to use. If you use find, try to query for the select element, not the selected option. If you use val() on the select element it should return the value of the selected option.

Comment: `var vl = $(this).parents('td').find('select').val();
alert('the selected value is:' + vl);`

the alert is giving me undefined the the vl.  What other ideas do you have?

Comment: Where do you use $(this)? If it's inside the CopyDown function you should pass a reference to it when calling the function, e.g. CopyDown(this, 'contactsbcuid', 1) and use that parameter instead. See: http://jsfiddle.net/RkYU8/

Comment: @nxt This is what I'm looking for but I'm surprised it worked.  You only defined one element in the function but three in the onClick.  How did this work?

Comment: I was just being lazy ;) Functions in javascript have a variable amount of arguments, so you could define a function with 3 arguments and use only 2 when calling it (the missing arguments will default to undefined). Or in my case the extra arguments are ignored (you could still access them using the arguments array)

Comment: @nxt  Lazy or just messing with my head?  :)  But joking aside, thank you.  This is working great and works pefectly for the dynamically added row.  There is another button on the page that allows a user to add an additional row of data and then saved with the form is submitted.  It is working perfectly and so much shorter (and cleaner) than was I was attempting.

Comment: Depending on what you want you could reduce your code even further by replacing all the onclick attributes with a single call to the jQuery delegate function. See http://jsfiddle.net/VkheB/ . This works by attaching a single event handler to a common parent element (table in my example) and since the handler is attached to a parent element it will continue to work when you dynamically add rows and because you'll only to attach the listener to a single element it won't matter how many rows you have.

Answer (score 0):

***[Is this jsFiddle what you are essentially looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/vqkbE/)***

jQuery:

```
$('span[id^="select_contactsbcuid"]').click(function() {

    var $select = $('select[name^="' + this.id.split("_")[1] + '"]');
    if ($select.length) { alert($select.val()); }

});
```

Comment: yes but the value needs to be obtained from a separate funciton.  also, I can't use the .change, it has to be a function.  The output set is very large and waiting for jQuery to apply all the selectors/methods to the code is creating a script message something to the effect, "This script it taking a long time to complete.  Do you want to cancel the script?  yes no"
I wanting to trigger this only when called, thus the button.

Comment: if you want to use this on a very large amount of elements it will take a long time to attach all the event handlers. You should consider using the jQuery delegate function so you can make use of event bubbling and reduce the amount of handlers

Comment: @nxt - I always use [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) in my code ... I was just showing an easy way to get the value the OP wanted.